# pivoting MS SQL Survey table

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Question             answer               group      enterprise
-------------------- -------------------- ---------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                    softcame             2022-09-01 softcame
2                    edgar                2022-09-01 softcame
5                    1                    2022-09-01 softcame
6                    1                    2022-09-01 softcame
3                    Si                   2022-09-01 softcame
4                    SI                   2022-09-01 softcame
1                    softcame america     2022-09-01 softcame america
2                    edgar 2              2022-09-01 softcame america
5                    2                    2022-09-01 softcame america
6                    2                    2022-09-01 softcame america
3                    No                   2022-09-01 softcame america
4                    No                   2022-09-01 softcame america
1                    softcame norte       2022-09-01 softcame norte
2                    edgar 3              2022-09-01 softcame norte
5                    3                    2022-09-01 softcame norte
6                    3                    2022-09-01 softcame norte
3                    Si                   2022-09-01 softcame norte
4                    No                   2022-09-01 softcame norte
```

I need to have the Question as columns and the answers as rows
if I use pivot this pivot code I got nulls

```
    SELECT [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6]
FROM   Respuestas_Encuestas_Todas
PIVOT
(
       max(answer)
       FOR no_pregunta in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6])
) AS P
where survey = 'SurveName' and group = '01/09/2022'
group by [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6]
```

I got this.

[image: Pivot]

Then I try with the case option but only get one row. this is the code

```
    SELECT grupo,  
    max(Case Question when 1 Then answer End) 1,
    max(Case Question when 2 Then answer End) 2,
    max(Case Question when 3 Then answer End) 3,
    max(Case Question when 4 Then answer End) 4,
    max(Case Question when 5 Then answer End) 5,
    max(Case Question when 6 Then answer End) 6 
    from                
    ((select Question,answer,grpup
            from Respuestas_Encuestas_Todas
            where survey = 'survey name' and grupo = '01/09/2022')) x
group by group
```

The result I need is this
[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBCfW.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
DECLARE 
    @columns NVARCHAR(MAX) = '', 
    @sql     NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

-- select the category names
SELECT 
    @columns+=QUOTENAME(NoPregunta) + ','
FROM [dbo].[Encuestas] WHERE Encuesta = 'Servicios Comité de Comerico Exterior' ORDER BY NoPregunta

SET @columns = LEFT(@columns, LEN(@columns) - 1);

 SET @sql = '
SELECT *
    FROM
    (
        SELECT Empresa, No_Pregunta, respuesta FROM [dbo].[Respuestas_Encuestas_Todas] 
        WHERE Encuesta = ''Servicios Comité de Comerico Exterior'' and grupo=''2022-09-01''
    ) AS TCursor
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(respuesta) FOR No_Pregunta IN ('+@columns+')
    ) AS TBPivot'
--SELECT @sql


EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).